# Dictionary doesn't seem to add new keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code, which I can't for the life of me figure out why it isn't working right:

```
def make_complete_graph(num_nodes):
    """Makes a complete graph, showing all possible edges for a given number of nodes"""
    ret={}
    for num in range(num_nodes):
        ret[num]=set([cnum for cnum in range(num_nodes) if cnum != num])
    return ret

def random_graph(n, m):
    ret=make_complete_graph(m)
    for x in range(m,n):
        ret[x]=set([random.choice(ret.keys()[:]) for x in range(m)])
    return ret
```

Specifically the random_graph doesn't seem to work. My test case is as follows:

> > print random_graph(4,3)
> >     {0: set([1,2]), 1:set([0,2]), 2: set([1,2])}

For some reason, I don't seem to be adding a value in the dictionary. In fact, I seem to be replacing the last entry in the dictionary, instead of adding a new value.

I have added debug code, changing the routine in to this, with the output as given:

```
def random_graph(n, m):
    ret=make_complete_graph(m)
    for x in range(m,n):
        ret[x]=set([random.choice(ret.keys()[:]) for x in range(m)])
        print x
        print ret
        print ret[x]
        print ret.keys()
    return ret
```

Output for the previous test case:

```
3
{0: set([1, 2]), 1: set([0, 2]), 2: set([0, 1])}
[0, 1, 2]
{0: set([1, 2]), 1: set([0, 2]), 2: set([0, 1, 2])}
```

I seem to be setting a key correctly (3), but the value for 2 is what is updated. I am running Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is only one local variable 'x', and you have used it for two purposes -- as the iterator in the set comprehension and as the iterator in the surrounding loop.  (If it helps -- the comprehension itself is not a scope, as it might be logically in math, it inherits the local scope.)

Comment: It didn't seem to warrant it.  This is not a question, it is either a tyro or a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one local variable 'x', and you have used it for two purposes -- as the iterator in the set comprehension and as the iterator in the surrounding loop.

If it helps -- the comprehension itself is not a scope, as it might be logically in math, it inherits the local scope.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy... I knew it must be something silly like that...